# Breezesharp EntityQuery with projection fail in Xamarin Release mode

Tags: android, xamarin, breeze-sharp

I have this Xamarin Application which works perfect in debug mode(emulator and device). In release mode(device) the application was well until the view with a Activity which a projection query. I removed linker configuration and the code optimization. I made some tests and the application doesn't work with basic projection/filtering options:

Not works(the original query. Works in debug mode but not in release mode)

```
var query = new EntityQuery<TransportReceipt>("GetAllByCustomer");
query = query.WithParameter("customerId", customerId);
```

Works

```
var query = new EntityQuery<TransportReceipt>("GetAll");
```

Not works

```
var query = new EntityQuery<TransportReceipt>("GetAll").Where(o => o.creationDate > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2));
```

Not works

```
var query = new EntityQuery<TransportReceipt>("GetAll").Expand(o => o.transportReceiptAttachments);
```

The image show the copy of device log.

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message

08-10 09:47:51.520  Samsung SM-J500M    Error   967 AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
... 1 more
08-10 09:47:51.520  Samsung SM-J500M    Error   967 AndroidRuntime  Caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Services.Client.TypeSystem' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
08-10 09:47:51.520  Samsung SM-J500M    Error   967 AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 09:47:51.520  Samsung SM-J500M    Error   967 AndroidRuntime  Parameter name: key
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException (System.ExceptionArgument argument) [0x00006] in <27d869918d7c4fc687b412573db27626>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].Insert (TKey key, TValue value, System.Boolean add) [0x00008] in <27d869918d7c4fc687b412573db27626>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].Add (TKey key, TValue value) [0x00000] in <27d869918d7c4fc687b412573db27626>:0 
  at System.Data.Services.Client.TypeSystem..cctor () [0x0061b] in <deb764142256426392349c18ced9aa88>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Data.Services.Client.ResourceBinder+PatternRules.MatchNonPrivateReadableProperty (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression e, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo& propInfo, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression& target) [0x00033] in <deb764142256426392349c18ced9aa88>:0
```

[image: Device log]

Comment: Is Proguard enabled in your release configuration? and please do not use images for errors, add the text (exception/stack trace) directly to your question.

Comment: Hi SushiHangover. Thanks for your comments. ProGard is disabled.

Comment: The error says "[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key]". You could  use the debugger to look at the data when it fails.

Comment: Hi. When I execute the application in debug no exception occurs. I disabled all Release code shrinking options. But still the same.

Comment: Is there any `WCF` reference in your project?

Comment: No WCF calls. Only a Xamarin Application with the Breezesharp client.

Comment: I decided to move to HttpClient after contact IdeaBlade team. Apparently BreezeSharp is not a up-to-date project.

Answer (score 0):

I decided move to .Net HttpClient approach because in the words of IdeaBlade team member, they doesn't support the project frequently because there is no many consulting works as javascript version has.